# Javascript / Qualtrics / Matrix Table - hide certain radio buttons for last row

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am using Qualtrics survey platform, I have a Matrix table (3 rows x 5 columns). For the last row, i would like to change radio button to check-box, and hide the remaining 2-5 columns/radio-buttons of row three only. I have to do this for over 100 questions, so am trying to get JavaScript code identify the question ID variable by itself, rather than specify it manually each time.

I am novice with regard to JavaScript but from reading around on the Qualtrics 'Example Code Snippets' page plus here, I've gotten this far (apologies if my poor effort below makes the JavaScript experts squirm):

```
/* automatically identify question ID/
var questionId = this.questionId;

/*carry forward Question ID & change row 3 column 1 radio to check-box/
document.getElementById("QR~"+this.questionId~3~1~TEXT').type='checkbox';
document.getElementById("QR~"+this.questionId~3~1~TEXT').display='hidden';

/*hide remaining columns/radio-buttons of column 3/
document.getElementById("QR~"+this.questionId~3~2~TEXT').display='hidden';
document.getElementById("QR~"+this.questionId~3~3~TEXT').display='hidden';
document.getElementById("QR~"+this.questionId~3~4~TEXT').display='hidden';
document.getElementById("QR~"+this.questionId~3~5~TEXT').display='hidden';
```

I've hit a wall regarding making this work, appreciate any pointers you could offer.